# Why python module not found on apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I have a problem with python and Django.

I have the error "Error was: No module named httplib2", so i installed httplib2. When i go on my console and type "import httplib2" it works!
But when i try to do that on my web page, it fails.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPd using a different version/install of Python than your REPL.

Comment: I only have one version installed on my compiuter. How can I check this?

Comment: Print something useful, like `sys.version` and/or `sys.executable`.

Comment: Install the module on the version/install that HTTPd is using.

Comment: Can you explain me how to choose on with version i install a module?

Comment: Run the installer with the executable for that version.